# Generate Websphere 6.1 compatible EAR file using Maven

Tags: java, maven-2, websphere, ear, rational-rsa

I've been looking around for some time and couldn't find a clear explanation for this.

We're using a Websphere server to run a Web application developed using Rational Software Architect 7. This application is composed of a war project and 4 jar projects. To make the final ear file there is a sixth project which contains the additional files needed by IBM to deploy it.

Currently we have to use RSA to genereate the ear file. I would like to use Maven to do that.

Apparently previous tries to use maven-ear plugin generated corrupted ears. It would appear thet they are missing the extra xml files needed by IBM.

I found a maven was-6 plugin, but it doesn't seem able to generate the file, only to install it on websphere. I couldn't find a clear description of what it does.

Does someone have any advice ? A link to some article ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: FWIW, those extra files are not required. You can build a generic EAR/WAR and deploy fine to WAS. You just then have to make some deploy-time associations, but this is what we prefer to do anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the maven-ear-plugin to generate your ear, but include the extra ibm specific config files as part of the earSourceDirectory property of that plugin.

The plugin will generate the generic application.xml file and the ibm specific file ibm-application-bnd.xmi and the contents of the ibmconfig directory can be rolled in by the plugin as well, just not generated.

Comment: Thanks robin for this hint, I will try that out after I sort some things out and let you know how it worked.

Comment: Also if you are using Maven make sure you specify the <executable>/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/bin/javac</executable> in your maven compiler plugin

Comment: I have no specific config files. I have only the normal application.xml. and I want to generate the ibm-application-bnd.xmi. What should I do in this plugin?